# AWS Lambda: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/task/node_modules/@types/nexus-typegen'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, enoent

I'm getting the following error on the Lambda cloudwatch logs

```
    ERROR   [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/task/node_modules/@types/nexus-typegen'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/var/task/node_modules/@types/nexus-typegen'
}
```

I tried modifying the webpack to force to bundle the dir, like:

```
 new CopyWebpackPlugin({
          patterns: [
            {from: "./node_modules/@types/nexus-typegen"}
         ]
     })
```

I also modify my prisma makeSchema to GenerateArtifacts: false

```
MakeSchema({
  types: typeDefs,
  plugins: [
    nexusPrisma({ experimentalCRUD: true, shouldGenerateArtifacts: false }),
  ]
```

But nothing have worked so far... does anyone have a workaround this?

Comment: any resolution? I'm getting something similar running `serverless offline` on a nodejs docker container